# PhP mailscript not working in PhP 8.0 or higher

Tags: php, php-7.4

For my sites I have been using a simple mailing script that gets parameters from a form and sends them to a specified email adress. The problem is that my host is now upgrading to php 8.0 or higher and the script stops working at 7.4.

I am not very familiar with PhP so it could be a small adjustment. The code is posted below and some things are redacted for privacy reasons. Could someone tell me what to change to make it working on 8.0?

```
<?php
    
if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$gender    = $_POST['gender'];
$firstname     = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname     = $_POST['lastname'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$send    = $_POST['send'];

$model    = $_POST['model'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$serial    = $_POST['serial'];

$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$mymail = 'XXXXXXXX';
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($firstname) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter name.</div>';
    exit();
}  else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter email.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter email</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter failure description</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}





$address = "XXXXXXXX";






$e_subject = 'Reparatiemelding van ' . $firstname . ' ' . $lastname . '.';




$e_body = "XXXXXXX" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$e_reply = "XXX" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers .= "From: $mymail" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    

     
header("Location: XXXXXXXXXX", true, 301);
exit();


    echo "<fieldset>";
        echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h1>Email succesvol verstuurd.</h1>";
    echo "<p>Bedankt <strong>$first_name</strong>, uw email is door ons ontvangen. We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met u op.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";


} else {

    echo 'Something went wrong, please contact repairs@mysoundrepair.com';

}
?>
```

Comment: What does not working mean? Do you have any errors in the web server error log?

Comment: `get_magic_quotes_gpc` is removed in php8. just remove the if statement

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php

Comment: "stops working" could mean anything. Please provide adequate technical info for us to understand what specific problem you're having. Have you checked error logs? Done any debugging? Or any other basic investigation to try and get to the problem?

Comment: The answer from Sysix was indeed correct, after removing this everything works. Thank you!